Is it possible to change the size of a specific dialog control at runtime in NSIS?
I created 5 custom pages.
While setup is in progress, I want to change the x, y coordinates or size of a specific control.

I tried the following but to no avail:
For example, change the y coordinate of the 1037 ID control from 15 to 20.
GetDlgItem $R0 $HWNDPARENT 1037
System::Call 'user32::MoveWindow(i$R0,i15,i20,i 280,i 18,i0)' 

(Assumes : Windows 7 or higher., NSIS3.x)

What is the value of $R0 after calling GetDlgItem? Are you sure it is returning the correct window? Are you sure $HWNDPARENT is the correct parent window of control 1037? You can use a tool like Spy++ to verify window relationships. Have you tried using FindWindow first like the GetDlgItem documentation suggests?

Thanks Remy :)
This was my mistake. ControlID should have been 1035, but I found out that I was applying 1037 incorrectly.

Maybe finish your previous question before starting another?

@tuxNeoh this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Please don't edit the question to provide a solution. I have reverted your edit. You can post your own answer instead, or else delete the question.

According to the  Remy Lebeau's suggestion:

You can use a tool like Spy++ to verify window relationships.

You should check the value of your controlID.
